# Checking a checkbox if checkbox value equals value in an arrayList

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc, checkbox, arraylist

I have an arrayList of values I'm using in my jsp file called "selectedMods". "selectedMods" contains the values of the previously checked checkboxes before form submission. I'd like for the checkboxes to remain checked when the form is refreshed. My line of thought here is that for each checkbox item, traverse the arraylist "selectedMods" of previously selected checkboxes and if that checkbox value equals any of the previously selected in "selectedMods" then check that checkbox. Here's the code for displaying the checkboxes:

```
 <c:forEach items="${modules}" var="module">
        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="moduleIds value="${module.id}"  /> ${module.title}</label>
 </c:forEach>
```

After "value" I thought about adding something like this:

```
 <c:if test="${selectedMods == ${module.id}">checked="checked"</c:if>
```

But I realize I can't compare a list of values against a single value without traversing the list and I'm not sure where to start. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a map of checked select inputs, where the key of an entry would be a module id, than your condition would be something like

```
<c:if test="${selectedMods.containsKey(module.id)}">
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. In order to use this in my jsp file what would I have to change in my controller? Apologies for the ignorance, I'm a bit new to this.

Comment: basically instead of populating the list, populate the map, the values that you've stored in the list, store as a key of a map entry, the accompanying value of an entry can be arbitrary as you're checking for the existence of the key only. Than place your map inside a model instead of the list. You can add to your question your controller method where you store the list in a model if you don't find your way

Comment: One more thing. After setting up the map and adding that to the jsp I get: "The function containsKey must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified". Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure that'll work. It keeps throwing an error at that line. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: In my view, this is the best way, add your method code, and changed jsp snippet, not sure what causes your other issue without looking at the code

Comment: I would think this should work fine. Here's my controller code: http://hastebin.com/yiwuwawazi.avrasm  Maybe I'm not doing something right in there?

Comment: seems ok to me, you can paste the jsp part, maybe an issue there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68503/discussion-between-master-slave-and-benign-baboon).